# Android device and emulator - Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Tags: android, eclipse

If I have both an Android device attached and an Android emulator running, when I click Run As Android Application, my app launches on the device with the message:

```
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

When the device is unattached it runs automatically on the virtual device.

However, I never get the dialog box that asks which device I want the app to run on.

How do I get the intermediary dialog box to come up so I can choose which device I want it to run on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally get that warning when your app is already running on the device (physical or emulated).

To get the device chooser:
(Menu item) Run, Run configurations, (Left pane) choose your app name, (Tab) choose Target, select "Always prompt", Apply, Close.

Since now on, **for that app**, you'll be propted to choose a running device or to start one.

Answer (score 2):

This means your app is already running and just brought to foreground instead of being started again.

Simply close the app by pressing the back button, and start it again from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I fix it?

There is nothing to fix This is not an `error`, as you can see it's just a `warning`.

> Why?

It means you had the app open in your device already, so it doesnt re-launch the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Project -Run As- Run Configuration then click on "target" tab.You can select option there- Always prompt to Pick device. Then Click Run at bottom

Answer (score 0):

i too get my self in same sort of situations so many times its simple because your physical device is not connected properly to system in my case when i unplug and reattach device i will get dialogue back asking you to choose in between . please make sure ur physical device is attached correctly and check ddms to see ur physical device is connected properly